# android draw stroke on multi line text

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, android-canvas, draw

Hi i'am trying to add stroke on multi line text but its not working
this is the code
first draw the fill text its works fine 
but when try to draw the stroke it's not work and give me something that not related to stroke

i need stroke like this but to multi line text
[stroke canvas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DP8Ty.png)

```
    textPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    textPaint.setTextSize(20);
    textPaint.setColor(Color.White);


    textPaint1.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    textPaint1.setStrokeWidth(20);
    textPaint1.setColor(Color.GREEN);


    StaticLayout sl = new StaticLayout(
            textLayer.getText(), // - text which will be drawn
            textPaint,
            boundsWidth, // - width of the layout
            Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER, // - layout alignment
            1, // 1 - text spacing multiply
            1, // 1 - text spacing add
            true); // true - include padding

    int boundsHeight = sl.getHeight();

    int bmpHeight = (int) (canvasHeight * Math.max(TextLayer.Limits.MIN_BITMAP_HEIGHT,
            1.0F * boundsHeight / canvasHeight));

    // create bitmap where text will be drawn
    Bitmap bmp;
    if (reuseBmp != null && reuseBmp.getWidth() == boundsWidth
            && reuseBmp.getHeight() == bmpHeight) {
        // if previous bitmap exists, and it's width/height is the same - reuse it
        bmp = reuseBmp;
        bmp.eraseColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); // erase color when reusing
    } else {
        bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(boundsWidth, bmpHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    }

    StaticLayout sl1 = new StaticLayout(
            textLayer.getText(), // - text which will be drawn
            textPaint1,
            boundsWidth, // - width of the layout
            Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER, // - layout alignment
            1, // 1 - text spacing multiply
            1, // 1 - text spacing add
            true); // true - include padding

    // calculate height for the entity, min - Limits.MIN_BITMAP_HEIGHT
    int boundsHeight1 = sl1.getHeight();

    int bmpHeight1 = (int) (canvasHeight * Math.max(TextLayer.Limits.MIN_BITMAP_HEIGHT,
            1.0F * boundsHeight1 / canvasHeight));

    Bitmap bmp1;
    if (reuseBmp != null && reuseBmp.getWidth() == boundsWidth
            && reuseBmp.getHeight() == bmpHeight1) {
        // if previous bitmap exists, and it's width/height is the same - reuse it
        bmp1 = reuseBmp;
        bmp1.eraseColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); // erase color when reusing
    } else {
        bmp1 = Bitmap.createBitmap(boundsWidth, bmpHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    }

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
    canvas.save();
    Canvas canvas1 = new Canvas(bmp1);
    canvas1.save();

    // move text to center if bitmap is bigger that text
    if (boundsHeight < bmpHeight) {
        //calculate Y coordinate - In this case we want to draw the text in the
        //center of the canvas so we move Y coordinate to center.
        float textYCoordinate = (bmpHeight - boundsHeight) / 2;
        canvas.translate(0, textYCoordinate);
    }

    // move text to center if bitmap is bigger that text
    if (boundsHeight1 < bmpHeight1) {
        //calculate Y coordinate - In this case we want to draw the text in the
        //center of the canvas so we move Y coordinate to center.
        float textYCoordinate = (bmpHeight1 - boundsHeight1) / 2;
        canvas1.translate(0, textYCoordinate);
    }

    //draws static layout on canvas
    sl.draw(canvas);
    sl1.draw(canvas1);
    canvas.restore();
    canvas1.restore();
```

and this to combine the bitmaps

```
Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp1.getWidth(), bmp1.getHeight(), bmp1.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas2 = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
    canvas2.drawBitmap(bmp, new Matrix(), null);
    canvas2.drawBitmap(bmp1, 0, 0, null);
    return bmOverlay;
    return bmp;
```

Comment: did you find-out the solution..? @Rft.hko

Answer (score 0):

You need to create two `StaticLayout` with the same text, but one with the text paint, the other with the stroke paint, then draw at the same position.